# command execute directory

Tags: python

i have to execute a command use python subprocess .

by default , command is execute as working on the directory where the python script file is . such as

```
 subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("ls -l"))
```

will list the file in the directory of the script file where is .

but i want this command to execute in another directory ,say , B .
   how can i do it .

i try this , but faild:

```
env['PWD'] = "/data/a"
f = tempfile.TemporaryFile('w+b')
p = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd),stdout= f,stderr=f,env=env)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ls -l` list all items in current directory default. You could tell command `ls -l` which directory to list by using `ls -l /your-path`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [os.chdir](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.chdir) or you use the cwd parameter to Popen.

Answer (score 0):

hi did u try changing the unix command

```
ls -l
```

to 
something like

```
ls -l /usr/share;
```

Comment: no , indeed i'm use execute the ls command , it's git command ,which can't put a path parameter.

Comment: can you say which command it is .. or use ; to combine two commands for eg: cd /var;ls